# How can I print what is happening in my program in debug mode

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'd like to print what's happening in my program in debug mode, but nothing should be print in release to not waste performance. My program is in C++

I'd like to see colors on what's printed. For example, if something happened that I know can lead to a major bug, I'd like to print a big red warning where I describe what happened, and then, close the program.

Is there a library for that ? What should I do to execute it only in debug mode ?

Comment: Macros and conditional compilation are common ways to solve this problem. And asking for library recommendations isn't [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to a "standard" mechanism for this would be to use the `NDEBUG` macro, which drives the behavior of `assert()`.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
std::cerr << "I only print in debug\n";
#endif
```

Most build systems like CMake will define `NDEBUG` when creating Release builds, so there's no additional work to do in those cases.

If you are invoking the compiler directly, then you need to manually define it. You almost certainly should be doing this already for release builds anyways:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -O3 main.cpp
```

However, sprinkling `#ifndef` blocks all over the place tends to not scale very well in larger codebases, so most non-trivial projects will have conditional-compilation featured as part of the logging/tracing system.

A simple version of that could look roughly like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef NDEBUG
  namespace my_project::details {
    struct null_sink {
      template<typename T>
      null_sink& operator<<(const T&) {return *this;}
    };
  }
  #define DEBUG_PRINT my_project::details::null_sink{}
#else
  #define DEBUG_PRINT std::cerr
#endif

void foo() {
  DEBUG_PRINT << "only in debug\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer of @Frank helped me very well, I have found a logging library that does what I need on [this github page](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog). This library is named spdlog.

I can log what is happening with colors, time, and the parameters needed.

We can merge this solution with the answer of @frank to obtain very good logging :

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
spdlog::warn("you are making a big mistake because of...")
#endif
```

will return :
[image]

Comment: As I said, all good logging systems provide conditional compilation out of the box. spdlog is no different. You should use the [macros](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/1.-QuickStart#logging-macros) that it already provides instead of using `#ifdef`. Also, you should really never compile out logs with a level above `debug`.